# display Java.util.Date in a specific format

Tags: java, date

I have the following scenario :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.parse("31/05/2011"));
```

gives an output

```
Tue May 31 00:00:00 SGT 2011
```

but I want the output to be

```
31/05/2011
```

I need to use parse here because the dates need to be sorted as Dates and not as String.

Any ideas ??

Comment: Can we add Wiki/FAQ entry or article for date parsing/formatting and timezones? Looks like 1 out of 5 Java questions are about this topic...

Comment: For latecomers: don’t use `Date` and certainly don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. Use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). For everyone: You are asking the impossible. A `Date` doesn’t have a format, and you cannot change how its `toString` method works (the same goes for the modern `LocalDate`)..

Comment: For a modern solution using *java.time*, see the Answers [by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54649203/642706) and [by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76841385/642706).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

How about:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse("31/05/2011")));

> 31/05/2011
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer is aaccepted. but it does not give the formatted date of type java.uti.Date. format () method returns String.

Comment: @RadhakrishnaGorenta, I'm not sure what you mean by that. There is no such thing "a formatted date of type java.uti.Date". Dates do not have "formats" until they are output on the screen or otherwise serialized. They are just objects.

Comment: How does this solve the question of "converting a `util.Date` to `sql.Date` object?

Comment: @Ephemeral which question are you talking about? There is no reference whatsoever to sql.Date...

Answer (score 55):

You need to go through [`SimpleDateFormat.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String%29) in order to format the date as a string.

Here's an example that goes from `String` -> `Date` -> `String`.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("31/05/2011");

System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));   // prints 31/05/2011
//                            ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 17):

Use the SimpleDateFormat.format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = new Date();
String sDate= sdf.format(date);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use simple date format in Java using the code below

```
SimpleDateFormat simpledatafo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date newDate = new Date();
String expectedDate= simpledatafo.format(newDate);
```

Answer (score 4):

It makes no sense, but:

```
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse("31/05/2011")))

SimpleDateFormat.parse() = // parse Date from String
SimpleDateFormat.format() = // format Date into String
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to simply output a date, just use the following:

```
System.out.printf("Date: %1$te/%1$tm/%1$tY at %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS%n", new Date());
```

As seen [here](http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2011/10/quick-formatting-of-date-using-a-java-string-format-expression/). Or if you want to get the value into a String (for SQL building, for example) you can use:

```
String formattedDate = String.format("%1$te/%1$tm/%1$tY", new Date());
```

You can also customize your output by following the [Java API on Date/Time conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt).

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

Here’s the modern answer.

```
    DateTimeFormatter sourceFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
    DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT)
            .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("zh-SG"));

    String dateString = "31/05/2011";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, sourceFormatter);
    System.out.println(date.format(displayFormatter));
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 31/05/11

See if you can live with the 2-digit year. Or use `FormatStyle.MEDIUM` to obtain `2011年5月31日`. I recommend you use Java’s built-in date and time formats when you can. It’s easier and lends itself very well to internationalization.

If you need the exact format you gave, just use the source formatter as display formatter too:

```
    System.out.println(date.format(sourceFormatter));
```

> 31/05/2011

I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead I use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

To obtain a specific format you need to format the parsed date back into a string. Netiher an old-fashioned `Date` nor a modern `LocalDate`can have a format in it.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

The question and the answers written at that time use `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` which was the right thing to do at that time. Java 8, released in March 2014, brought the modern date-time API.  It is recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API entirely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

### Your problem

You are trying to parse the date string into a `java.util.Date` object and print it. A `java.util.Date` object represents only the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. When you print its object, the string returned by [`Date#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--), which applies your system's timezone, is printed. Note that a date-time object holds only date-time information, not a format. A format is represented using a string you obtain by formatting the date-time object using a date-time formatting class with the desired pattern.

### Modern Date-Time API

The following [table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) shows an overview of different types available in the modern Date-Time API.

[image]

The type, `LocalDate` fits your requirement. You can use different patterns for parsing and formatting using a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). The following example uses the same pattern for parsing and formatting:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "31/05/2011";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, dtf);
        System.out.printf("Default format: %s, Custom format: %s%n", date, date.format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Default format: 2011-05-31, Custom format: 31/05/2011
```

[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/NC7gUj)

**Note:** Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573). Also, [never use `DateTimeFormatter` for custom formats without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

You already has this (that's what you entered) `parse` will parse a date into a giving format and print the full date object (`toString`).

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
print (df.format(new Date());

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this, my suggestion would be to use java for things like this, don't put in boilerplate code

[image: BasicImplementation]

Answer (score 0):

This looks more compact. Finishes in a single line.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateFormatUtils;

System.out.println(DateFormatUtils.format(newDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```