# Jasper Report Date Format

Tags: date, jasper-reports, format, reverse, crosstab

In Jasper Reoprt, crosstab, I have displayed my date as like "2012-09-13". Is there a way to display it in reverse as "13-09-2012" using any String methods? And another thing is that I retrieve the date from SQL dB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the above in the query level itself instead of doing it on ireport.

You may want to refer to the below link on how to format dates
[format date](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

In ireport, you can use **SimpleDateFormat/DateFormat** and format your dates as you require
You can refer the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rashmi Nagaraja..!

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, kindly accept the same.Since this will help others as well.