# String to Date object conversion with custom format

Tags: java, date, datetime, java.util.date

I need to convert a date in dd/MM/yyyy format and store it to a Date object.
i tried but not getting the desired result.My code :

```
    Date date=new Date();
    System.out.println("Normal Date :"+date);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String strdate=formatter.format(date);
    System.out.println("String date: "+strdate);
    date=(Date)formatter.parse(strdate);
    System.out.println("Formated Date : "+date);
```

Current output

---

Normal Date :Wed Feb 18 10:54:40 IST 2015

String date: 18/02/2015

**Formated Date : Wed Feb 18 00:00:00 IST 2015**

Desired output

---

Normal Date :Wed Feb 18 10:54:40 IST 2015

String date: 18/02/2015

**Formated Date : 18/02/2015**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `System.out.println("Formated Date : "+formatter.format(date));`?

Comment: Remember, the "format" is irrelevant.  It's the data that's important.  `Date` is just a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch, it carries no notion of formatting.  When you want to display the date, use an appropriate `DateFormat`

Comment: @MadProgrammer, i have this constraint on the column. @Column(name="from", nullable=false, length=10). so can't store complete date. it returns an error. and i'm not autorized to change that

Comment: Then the only choice is to use something like `formatter.format(date)` and store it as text

Comment: possible duplicate of [display Java.util.Date in a specific format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in database as
`sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());`

Answer (score 0):

Date Object can be created from a specific format but when you print it, it will always print as per its `.toString()` implementation.

So you wont be able to achieve what you are trying to.

Answer (score 0):

Date object stores date in international standards. if you want to print the way you want use this.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(yourdate));
```

possible duplicate of [display Java.util.Date in a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format)

Comment: Actually its not for just a display purpouse. I need to store it on database.                                              @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="from", nullable=false, length=10)
    public Date getFrom() {
        return this.from;
    }
    
    public void setFrom(Date from) {
        this.from = from;
    } The max lenth is 10

Comment: @Dev, then store it in database.

Comment: @Dev then you can store it in the database as a varchar. But I don't understand why you store it like that because then the comparison of dates in the database would be messy. 

it is good practice to store date as a SQL Date  and whenever displaying the date, format it at will

Comment: @Dev `Date` is just a container for the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch, it does not carry any formatting information.  Simply store the `Date` value into the database as is, assuming that the column supports a date value

Comment: @prasadmadanayake , if i change type to varchar i can store it. But i'm not authorized to do so. that's why i am asking a question like this

Comment: @Dev then you should just store it as a SQL Date Object.  formatting only necessary only when displaying . manipulating of the date will be handled by SQL engine. just store the date as it is and format it when displying

Comment: then you should just store it as a SQL Date Object.  formatting only necessary only when displaying . manipulating of the date will be handled by SQL engine. just store the date as it is and format it when displying