# How to get date from sql database without hours, minutes and seconds(only yyyy-MM-dd)?

Tags: java, mysql, printing

```
orders[index][6]=rs.getDate("dateArriving");
SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");                       
orderDate = formattedDate.parse(orderDateCon);
```

This is my line for getting the date
and this is what i use to store the date:

so when i print orderDate, i get a result like this: Thu Nov 26 00:00:00 GMT 2015
I want the date to be printed so that the result is only Thu Nov 26 20125, without 00:00:00.
+extra question, how to get the 00:00:00 to be stored in a normal way, because the time should be, for example, if the date is stored now, Thu Nov 26 22:14:50 GMT 2015

Explaining the question in more details:

....code....

```
String orderDateCon = menu.ordersList.get(y).getOrderDate().toString();
```

....code....

```
while(y < menu.ordersList.size())
                {
                    formattedDate.format(formattedDate.parse(orderDateCon));
                        orderData[y][0] = (menu.ordersList.get(y).getProductName()); 
                        orderData[y][1] = (menu.ordersList.get(y).getQuantity()); 
                        orderData[y][2] = (menu.ordersList.get(y).getProductCost()); 
                        orderData[y][3] = (menu.ordersList.get(y).getTrademark()); 
                        orderData[y][4] = formattedDate.format(formattedDate.parse(orderDateCon));//(menu.ordersList.get(y).getOrderDate()); 
                        orderData[y][5] = (menu.ordersList.get(y).getArriveDate()); 


                        y++;
            }
```

This code i use to store the data into a table, but this error i get: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Nov 26 00:00:00 GMT 2015"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display Java.util.Date in a specific format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format)

Comment: Use a DateFormat of some kind to print the date value in the format you want. Date is just s container for the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch

Answer (score 0):

You should use a query like this:

```
select to_char(dateArriving, 'YYYY-mm-dd') as dateArriving from tablename ;
```