# Parse dates from one format to another

Tags: scala, date, parsing, localdate

I have an initial date as a String which I need to convert to date with a specific format. I tried to defined date format in a string and parse it, then I formatted it to the desired format. The problem is that I need a date as a final result.
Here is the code I used:

```
  def parseDateToOriginal(date: String): String = {
    val initialDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy")
    val finalDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")

    val result = finalDateFormat.format(initialDateFormat.parse(date))
    result
  }
```

So I need Date as the return type for this method. I tried to parse the result string to get a proper date but for some reason, the result defaults back to the original date format. How can I fix this problem?

Here is how I tried to parse it again:

```
val parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(parseDateToOriginal(date))
```

The result is of the pattern `"EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display Java.util.Date in a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format)

Comment: You are asking the impossible. A `Date` cannot have a format. Also I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And also using `zzz` for parsing is inherently unsafe since time zone abbreviations are ambiguous (I think more often than not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def parseDateToOriginal(date: String): String = {
  LocalDateTime
    .parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"))
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
}
```

which outputs

```
parseDateToOriginal("Thu Jun 18 20:56:02 EDT 2009") // res2: String = 2009-06-18
```

---

Note you have a bug in the format of `finalDateFormat`

```
val finalDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd")
```

You are using lowercase `mm` in the month positions, but should be upper case `MM`. Lowercase `mm` represents minutes, so it would erroneously result in `res2: String = 2009-56-18` as outputs.

Comment: The `mm` bug is nicely spotted. The questioner additionally erroneously has got lowercase `hh` in the other format pattern. You have corrected it in your code.

Answer (score 4):

First, `SimpleDate` is old and outdated. The current `java.time` library is recommended.

Next, if you need to return a `Date` then parse the input and return the `Date`. You need to format a `Date` only when you present it, i.e. change it to a `String`.

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

def parseToDate(date: String): LocalDate = 
  LocalDate.parse(date
                 ,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy"))
```