# Android - Date doesn't correspond to given format

Tags: android, date, datetime, kotlin, simpledateformat

I got the following variables to begin with the conversion process of a date:

```
val format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale("pt", "PT"))
```

Until here everything ok. Then I got some values (`val_1` and `val_2`) that correspond to dates(like this "01/01/2001" in string) picked up from `editexts`. (I don't think this is important to write, but gives the question some context).
The problem is that I want the date to have first the day, then the month and finally the year, just like the `format`... but this is what android gives:

[image]

As you can see, it gives me first the month, then the day...and in this way, my program doesn't work at all. Whan can I do?

Comment: Exactly in which formate you want those dates `dateFromConvert` and `dateToConvert`?

Comment: bro image that you attached  is showing the value of dateFromConvert and dateToConvert which is correct, check the Log , Log will give you the right value which you have print. you need to store the value after formating  is done then check that value

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA I want this "dd-MM-yyyy" and it gives me that big string with the month first...

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display Java.util.Date in a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format)

Comment: The string `Wed Jul 24 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019` is the result of `Date.toString()`. Apparently your debugger calls the `toString` method to get a string to show you (what else could it do?) It doesn’t matter. If you need to output the date to the user, format it back into a string.

Comment: In an attempt to understand your goal better (and not as a serious suggestion): If your string is correct, why not just use that instead of your `Date`?

Comment: Just replace `format.format(dateFromConvert)` with  `sdf.format(dateFromConvert)` in both `println`. This will print the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
val sdf = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale("pt", "PT")).toString();
```

or:

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale("pt", "PT")).toString();
```