# Array of Instants from Strings

Tags: java, datetime, arraylist, java.time.instant

I have an ArrayList that I want to be type Instant, but no matter what I try to do on the array it just does not let me convert it to Instant format. The error is that it tries to add a String to an ArrayList of Instants.

```java
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class LiveData {
    private final String location;
    private final String metric;
    private Double data = null;
    private Instant timestamp = null;
}

private void onConnectionOpened() {
        try {
            int i = 0;
            final List<Sensor> sensors = clientConnection.querySensors().get();
            final List<String> metric = sensors.stream().map(sensor -> sensor.getLocation()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            final List<String> location = sensors.stream().map(sensor -> sensor.getMetric()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<Instant> timestamps = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Instant> times = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Double> datavalues = new ArrayList<>();
            while (i < sensors.size()) {
                final DataPoint data = clientConnection.queryValue(new Sensor(location.get(i), metric.get(i))).get();
                timestamps.add((Util.TIME_FORMAT.format((new Date(data.getTime()).toInstant()))));
                datavalues.add(data.getValue());
                i++;
            }

            i = 0;
            List<LiveData> testcol = new ArrayList<>();
            while (i < sensors.size()) {
                //LiveData temporary = new LiveData(location.get(i), metric.get(i));
                LiveData temporary = new LiveData(location.get(i), metric.get(i), datavalues.get(i), timestamps.get(i));
                testcol.add(temporary);
                i++;
            }
            ObservableList<LiveData> livedata = FXCollections.observableArrayList(testcol);
            Platform.runLater(() ->
                    tvData.setItems(livedata));
            //Thread.sleep(10000);
            //onConnectionOpened();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to have the ArrayList of Instants and than use it like this:

```
LiveData temporary = new LiveData(location.get(i), metric.get(i), datavalues.get(i), timestamps.get(i));
```

For later use in TableView.

I am formatting the `Instant` objects. I use that format in order to have a nicer output of the actual timestamp because now it looks like this: 2019-07-18T05:35:00Z. And I want it to be 2019-07-18 07:35:00.

Comment: What is the type of `Util.TIME_FORMAT`? And why are you trying to format the `Instant` objects at all? An `Instant` cannot have a format. Could you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: I use that format in order to have a nicer output of the actual timestamp because now it looks like this: ```2019-07-18T05:35:00Z```. And I want it to be ```2019-07-18 07:35:00```. I provided more code.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I didn’t intend to ask for *more* code. A minimal, reproducible example is more about stripping away the parts of the code that don’t contribute directly to demonstrating the problem asked about. [Please read the text in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will be nice to know also for your next many questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `data.getTime()` returns a `long`, you just want

```
    timestamps.add(Instant.ofEpochMilli(data.getTime()));
```

No need to mix in the old and poorly designed `Date` class, that will just complicate things needlessly. And no use trying to format. An `Instant` cannot have a format.

It’s not completely clear without the full context, but probably `Util.TIME_FORMAT.format()` returns a `String`, so you were trying to add this `String` to your list, which caused the error message that you referred to:

> The error is that it tries to add a String to an ArrayList of
>   Instants.

In your comment you said:

> I use that format in order to have a nicer output of the actual
>   timestamp because now it looks like this: `2019-07-18T05:35:00Z`. And
>   I want it to be `2019-07-18 07:35:00`.

I am sorry, that’s wrong. In all but the simplest throw-away programs you should keep your model and your UI separate. The `Instant` objects belong in your model. Your nice output — of course you should have a nice output, only it belongs in your user interface. So what you want and need to do is format the `Instant` before outputting it (not before putting it into the list). And I repeat: An `Instant` cannot have a format.

Related questions, only asking about the now outdated `Date` with a format:

- [display Java.util.Date in a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format).
- [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format). I have tried to write [a thorough answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485250/5772882).

Comment: That is not the format I want for my Instant, but it has to be an Instant.
I use that format in order to have a nicer output of the actual timestamp because now it looks like this: ```2019-07-18T05:35:00Z```. And I want it to be ```2019-07-18 07:35:00```

Comment: I have edited to address this (impossible, sorry) requirement.