# Date format issue using LocalDate

Tags: java, datetime

I need to convert a `Date object`(it shows this in debug mode---> "Mon Sep 23 00:00:00 EDT 2019") to another `Date object` having "yyyy-MM-dd" format.

I tried the following code, but I get a runtime error saying:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Mon Sep 23 00:00:00 EDT
>   2019' could not be parsed at index 0.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date.toString(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
Date result = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

Thanks for your help!.

Comment: What you see in the debugger is formatted by a custom formatter of your IDE. `toString()` has it's own format. However, you should use java conversion methods to change between date and localdate.

Comment: Don't rely on the result from `toString`

Comment: You can’t. A `Date` hasn’t got, as in cannot have a format. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format) or [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485250/5772882). Also what do you want an old-fashioned `Date` for when you can have a modern `LocalDate`?

Answer (score 3):

### Your error

What you see in the debugger is formatted by a custom formatter of your IDE. `Date.toString()` has it's own format. However, you should use java conversion methods to change between date and localdate

Here is an except on `date.toString()`:

> The toString() method of Java Date class converts this date object
>   into a String in form “dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyy”. This method
>   overrides toString in class object.

[Source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/date-tostring-method-in-java-with-examples/)

The pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd"` is not compatible with this.

Why are you doing this however? There are better ways to convert a `Date` into a `LocalDate`.

### Convert Date to LocalDate (& Vice Versa)

Try the following:

```
public LocalDate convertToLocalDateViaInstant(Date dateToConvert) {
    return dateToConvert.toInstant()
      .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
      .toLocalDate();
}

public Date convertToDateViaSqlDate(LocalDate dateToConvert) {
    return java.sql.Date.valueOf(dateToConvert);
}
```

[Source](https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-to-localdate-and-localdatetime)

Answer (score -1):

`Date` objects are `Date`, nothing else. String rapresentation of `Date` objects could have format. I think this

```
new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(date);
```

is the only thing you need.

Comment: While it’s correct please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.