# Simple Date time gives the wrong format of date

Tags: android, kotlin, simpledateformat

```
class TimeStampFormat {

    private val recordDtmFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH)
   // private val recordDtmFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale("en","IN"))
    fun getTimeStamp(): Date{
        return recordDtmFormat.parse(Calendar.getInstance().time.toString())!!
    }
    fun parseDate(date:Date):Date {
        return recordDtmFormat.parse(recordDtmFormat.format(date))!!.also {
           Log.i("mpurusharth","last $it")
        }
    }
    fun formatDate(time : String):Date{
        return recordDtmFormat.parse(time)!!.also {
            Log.i("mpurusharth","last $it")
        }
    }
```

my default date is supposed to be the first day of the year which I get by

```
   val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,0,1)
        val date = calendar.time
```

when I pass the date to the function it gives the wrong format of date

```
lastSyncDttm = TimeStampFormat().parseDate(date)
```

gives

```
last Tue Jan 01 13:09:48 GMT+05:30 1
```

why is the date not properly formatted.
Even if I use the `formatDate` function and pass a string the format is still incorrect what am I missing ??

Comment: I'm not able to understand what's the issue here! can you please elaborate?

Comment: when I am using the format pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`
any the output should be `2021-02-01 13:09:48`   but what I get is `Tue Jan 01 13:09:48 GMT+05:30 1`

Comment: the output format is completely different for some reason
it it in the format of `E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z` and there is a `1` at the end for some reason

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: A `Date` hasn’t got, as in cannot have a format. So when you print the ´Date`, you are just getting the return value from uts `toString` method which is always in the format you obsertved, `Tue Jan 01 13:09:48 GMT+05:30 1` (for January 1 year 1 AD).

Comment: Your `fun formatDate(time : String):Date` is parsing, not formatting. Those are opposite operations. Maybe the method name confused yourself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display Java.util.Date in a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time through desugaring

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work.

To get the first day of the current year — excuse my Java syntax:

```
    LocalDate firstDayOfThisYear
            = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).withDayOfYear(1);
    System.out.println("First day of the year: " + firstDayOfThisYear);
```

Output so far:

> First day of the year: 2021-01-01

To format into your desired format:

```
    String formattedDate = firstDayOfThisYear.atStartOfDay()
            .format(RECORD_DTM_FORMAT);
    System.out.println("Formatted date: " + formattedDate);
```

I used this static formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter RECORD_DTM_FORMAT
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

> Formatted date: 2021-01-01 00:00:00

### What went wrong in your code?

One error is in this line:

```
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,0,1)
```

You were finding the first day, not of this year, but of year 1 AD (2020 years ago). You were using the constant `Calendar.YEAR` incorrectly. It’s a constant to use for accessing the year field of a `Calendar` object and has the value 1. So you were specifying year 1. It was a common mistake with `Calendar`. In your output you can see that you get year 1 (the digit 1 at the end):

> last Tue Jan 01 13:09:48 GMT+05:30 1

You also notice that the call to `set()` has not got rid of the time of day, which you might have wanted to.

This method call effectively does nothing (or really very little):

```
    recordDtmFormat.parse(recordDtmFormat.format(date))
```

You are formatting a `Date` object into a `String` only to parse it back into a `Date` object again. What you get is a `Date` object equal to the one you had. Only the millisecond of the second has been discarded because they are not in your string format. It’s the only difference.

A couple of further details that don’t contribute to your unexpected output, but you still might like to know: You have commented out this line:

```
// private val recordDtmFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale("en","IN"))
```

Hardcoding `T` as a literal in your format pattern string is correct since there should always be a `T` there and it doesn’t carry any semantics. The `Z` carries semantics: it’s an offset of 0 from UTC. So you must never hardcode it as a literal in your format pattern string. You need to parse it as an offset, or you will get an incorrect result.

Also in your output it seems that you have set your default time zone to `GMT+05:30`. This is incorrect for India. You need to set it to Asia/Kolkata. Always use the *region/city* format for time zones. While both give the same results for dates in this year, there are differences for historic dates and there may come differences again for future dates if the Indian politicians decide to change India’s time zone offset again some time. Experiences from other parts of the world say that this happens a lot.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- On newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- On older Android use desugaring. See the link below.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not getting your desired output format in the log is because you're trying to print "date" object directly while not formatting it.

Whenever you try to print object directly as in output, it would be represented by `toString()` method provided from that class or from it's super. That's the reason you're not getting your desired output while you put this:

```
Log.i("mpurusharth","last $it")
```

Instead try this:

```
Log.i("mpurusharth","last ${recordDtmFormat.format(it)}")
```

Here, using `format()` from recordDtmFormat will generate your desired output.